# Game Hangs When Moving External Mouse, Works Fine With Trackpad

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, games

I have a Logitech external wired mice connected via a USB type-c hub. When I play this game called "Insurgency" and move the external mouse, the game starts hanging - FPS drops significantly, and gets fine as soon as I stop moving the mouse. It shows no problems with the trackpad, however. This doesn't happen always, rather only around 70% times.

I've installed the latest Logitech G Hub app and the OS, Steam and the game itself are up-to-date. What could be the issue?

Comment: MacOS Catalina? If no one has a good answer in a few days, make an edit to your question to bump it once with some specifics of your OS

Comment: @bmike yes, Catalina.